# You will be surprised - which tense is it?

Tags: grammaticality

It can't be the future continuous because there isn't ing form. Is it the simple future?

Comment: Yes, *will be* is the simple future

Comment: will+be+ing is called future continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

> - future tense: *will / shall  + vb. (short inf.)* => **will be**
> - passive voice: _to be + vb. (past participle)) => **be surprised**

Comment: In that case, would you say that the active voice of the sentence, could be also "That will surprise you"

Comment: Yes, correct: That will surprise you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is ***simple future***, there is a will, which implies that it will be in the future. But the fact that there is no unfinished action, just the action of being surprised.

Answer (score 1):

> *You will be surprised.*

Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has two tenses: present "will" and preterite "would".

Semantically, "Will" is used to make
reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe), and that is exactly what it is doing in your example.

Thus, your example is present tense with a future time meaning.

Comment: Would you say that is a passive voice as well?

Comment: Yes, it's passive.